# Estou tentando copiar os campos coluna de uma tabela para outra trabela já criada, porém, estou recebendo esse erro

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
UPDATE variaveis_copy 
 SET descricao = (
  SELECT descricao FROM variaveis WHERE variaveis.variavel = variaveis_copy.variavel
 )
```

> (ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression)

Comment: A mensagem é clara. Utilize a chave primária para correlacionar as tabelas ou escolha apenas uma das descrições retornadas.

Comment: sua subquery esta retornando mais de uma linha e isso da erro no update, que esta esperando so uma linha